# How to set column width for all the columns at once in APEX Interactive Grid

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-23

I am creating an interactive report in Oracle APEX, However the columns are overlapping and i am not able to find an option to set the column width for all at once like auto alignment.

Please help me on this.

I tired to find options at region level and Attribute level but no luck

Comment: Interactive grid or interactive report ? Title says IG, details state IR what is it ? Please clarify “columns are overlapping”

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, you can not.

It'll take some time to adjust widths, one-by-one.

- click the "Action" button
- choose "Columns"
- pick column one by one and set appropriate width property
- once you're done, don't forget to **save** report settings (again in "Actions"); if you don't, your next session will override all settings you've made with default ones, and report (OK, *grid*) will look ugly again.

Comment: unfortunately this is the only way. there should be a select all/apply all function.